# Why scipy minimize function returns nan values

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to solve an optimization problem using scipy.optimize library in python. The problem can be described as below :

1- The optimization variable is a matrix Z of dimension 7x23

2- Each row of the matrix has a different constraint as given by the constraint function in the code below. c1,c2,c3.. are constants.

3- Each entry of this matrix is a real number between 0 and 1.

4- Initially, a PDF is evaluated based on the given data. This best distribution is stored in variable best_dist. (code for this evaluation is not shown)

5- The objective function 'objfunc' calculates CDF inverse for each entry of the matrix z and adds them up.

6- The constraints are checked for each each to see if they satisfy.
Bounds checks if the values are within 0 and 1.

However, the code below returns nan values for the number of iterations gets exceeded. When I try to change the starting point z0 and the step size, I either get the initial value as solution or a value very close to the initial solution with message "Positive directional derivative for linesearch". What could be plausible reason for this ? Is the problem formulation or approach incorrect ? How can it be resolved? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The changed the objective function's return value to smaller number by dividing by a large number to do away with "Positive directional derivative for linesearch" message. That seems to have worked but now I get the below error when I run the minimize function :

original_shape = list(np.shape(np.atleast_1d(sequence[0].squeeze())))

IndexError: list index out of range

from the numdifftools library, which is used to calculate the Hessian and derivative. If I remove the two functions fun_hess(x) and fun_der(x), the error goes away but the returned solution is just nan values and success flag is set to False and message: 'Iteration limit exceeded'. I would believe numdifftools is unable to calculate the Hessian but I am not sure why. Also, why would nan values be returned by minimize function ?

EDIT2: Using Nelder Mead gives a solution successfully but it doesn't take into consideration the bounds. Is there a way to use constraints with it ?

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#import distribu
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
from numdifftools import Jacobian, Hessian

def objfunc():
 inv_sum=0
 for i in range(7):
    inv_sum+= np.sum(best_dist.ppf(z[i],*params_global))
return inv_sum

def fun_hess(x):
    return Hessian(lambda x: objfunc(x))(x)

def fun_der(x):
    return Jacobian(lambda x: objfunc(x))(x).ravel()


con1 = {'type': 'ineq','fun' : constraint2  }
con2 = {'type': 'ineq','fun' : constraint3  }
con3 = {'type': 'ineq','fun' : constraint4  }
con4 = {'type': 'ineq','fun' : constraint5  }
con5 = {'type': 'ineq','fun' : constraint6  }
con6 = {'type': 'ineq','fun' : constraint7  }

cons = [con1, con2, con3, con4, con5, con6]

bounds = []
b = (0.0, 1.0)

for i in range(161):
    bounds.append(b)
z0 = np.zeros((7,23))
```

The constraints functions are of the form

```
def constraint2(z):
    market = 'India'
    u = 0.98
    p = objfunc2(z[0]) - c2*u
    return p
def constraint3(z):
    market = 'APSC Hub88'
    u = 0.80
    p = objfunc2(z[1]) - c3*u
    return p
def constraint4(z):
    market = 'China HOCO'
    u=0.98
    p = objfunc2(z[2]) - c3*u
    return p
def constraint5(z):
    market = 'Indonesia'
    u = 0.95
    p = objfunc2(z[3]) - c4*u
    return p
def constraint6(z):
    market = 'Korea'
    u = 0.95
    p = objfunc2(z[4]) - c5*u
    return p
def constraint7(z):
    market = 'Philippines'
    u=0.95
    p = objfunc2(z[5]) - c6*u
    return p
def constraint8(z):
    market = 'Thailand'
    u=0.90
    p = objfunc2(z[6]) - c7*u
    return p
```

And I am using minimize function as below

```
res = minimize(objfunc, z0, method='SLSQP',

                 constraints=cons,  bounds=bounds
                 )
```

Comment: Which part of the code returns `nan`? And what is `objfunc2`? At the top you are showing `objfunc` instead and I do not see how it would return `nan`.
Also your constraints depend on some variables `c2` etc. which are not defined..

Comment: Updated objfunc2. The minimize function returns res object which contains solution. The solution is turning out to be nan values. Also, c1,c2,c3.. are constants. When I try to change the starting point z0 and the step size, I either get the initial value as solution or a value very close to the initial solution with message "Positive directional derivative for linesearch".

Comment: Please update also your question with any additional info you are providing here in the comments section.